# Interesting, open datasets for scoring of location attractiveness?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm considering the problem of assessing attractiveness of location of "some stuff". I don't want to provide too many examples since they could bias your ideas and suggestions... Say, we could evaluate attractiveness of houses (measured by their price) with respect to their characteristics (for this example I've found some data, I'm looking for some more interesting options).

Any suggestions and examples of datasets for this problem?

Comment: Do you mean "location" like latitude/longitude, or proximity to other things?

Comment: I meant location rather in the sense of latitude/longitude. However, proximity can be a very important factor for this problem. But once I have latitude and longitude of e.g. a house and sport facilities in the area, I can compute proximity to the closest one to that house.

Comment: Any specific country in mind?

Comment: Thanks for both comments. As far as the country is concerned, I was primarily interested in US, but other examples would be good as well.

Comment: http://illustreets.co.uk/ does a good job at looking at this situation and they list their data here: http://illustreets.co.uk/about-illustreets/

Answer (score 3):

Often those data are released at a local level and the country / city you are interested in will defined what data are available.

For example the city of Toronto (Canada) have build a Well Being application to map and weight hundreds of indicators: http://map.toronto.ca/wellbeing/ Once you selected the indicators, you can export the row data.

This is just an example. Indication on what municipality you are interested in will help to narrow down the answer.

Comment: Your comment made me think of SimCity -- you were able to overlay the map with various metrics (police & fire response, pollution traffic, etc.).  It's possible that school zones, [crime](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/381/263), tree canopy, green spaces, noise levels and other information might be a factor in 'attractiveness' other than just what the buildings look like (which what I first assumed from the question)

Answer (score 3):

The Data Science Toolkit is really awesome.  It has a tool called Coordinates to Statistics which can pull a whole host of stats from average rainfall and temperature to employment rates, average age of population and mean salary per household.  See the list of options [here](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#coordinates2statistics).

A while back I used Data Science Toolkit through OpenRefine (formerly called GoogleRefine), and did a little write-up of my notes.  If you're interested you can [find those here](http://pdb.space/dst.or/).